# table diff patch algorithm for UITableView

Tags: ios, algorithm, uitableview, diff, patch

I am using UITableView to display a set of objects which are persisted on a server. Server notifies client to pull out the new set whenever it detects a change. I don't like to reload the entire table. I need an algorithm to patch the old table with insert,move,reload and delete operations so it would transform into the new set. What would be the simplest algorithm to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i should have googled it first, for those who end up here for answers;

https://github.com/khanlou/NSArray-LongestCommonSubsequence